# How to pass meta data along with paged list using Paging 3 library

Tags: android, android-paging-3

I am using Android Paging 3 beta library to load the paginated list in recycler view and using MVVM architecture.

I need to pass additional meta data like the common info about the page to the view but the [PagingSource.LoadResult.Page](http://httpshttps://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/paging/PagingSource.LoadResult.Page) is designed in a way to return only the list of items to the view.

Here are few options which I thought about:

- Using a live data to pass the meta data independently
- Reading the meta data directly from the database or In Memory Cache

What would be the best approach? Any other better suggestions?